# Prove that bilinear forms are the same if and only if $A=B$

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, bilinear-form

I am looking for help or a direction to prove that $x^TAy=x^TBy$ if and only if $A=B$.

So far I've been using inner product and trace, for example for quadratic form I've used trace to prove $x^TAx=x^TBx$ if and only if $A+A^T=B+B^T$, but how is bilinear form different, shouldn't same approach apply here.

Lets say:
$$x^TAy=x^TBy$$
$$tr(x^TAy)=tr(x^TBy)$$
$$tr(x^TAy)-tr(x^TBy)=0$$
$$tr(x^T(A-B)y)=0=tr(x^T(A-B)^Ty)$$
which means that the solution with either be $ A=B $ or $(A-B)$ is skew symmetric $(trace=0)$

What am I doing wrong here? It should be only if $A=B$

Comment: Take $x=e_i$ and $y=e_j$, where $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors. You get $a_{ij}=b_{ij}$ for all $i,j$. Alternatively, note that $x^T(A-B)y=0$ for all $x$ means that $(A-B)y$ has $0$ dot product with every vector. Hence $(A-B)y=0$. Since this is true for every $y$ we have $A-B=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have $x^T (A - B) y = 0$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n $

Using the standard basis, we can write:

${e_i}^T (A - B) {e_j} = 0 $ for all $i, j$,

but $(e_i^T (A - B) e_j )$ is just the $i,j$-th entry of $(A - B)$

Hence $A - B$ must be the zero matrix, from which it follows that $ A = B$

Comment: Does this mean, that the trace cannot be used in this case? Because $tr(A-B)=0$ holds also for skew-symmetric matrix, which is true for quadratic form $x^TAx$.

Comment: I am not sure about the trace.